# Atom error: "Failed to spawn command python3: Make sure python3 is installed and on your PATH"

Tags: python, atom-editor

I'm using MacOS and Atom as a text editor to write and execute python scripts. I get the following error upon beginning to type (box in upper right corner appears w/ a split-screen that has a bunch of HTML appear)

"Failed to spawn command python3. Make sure python3 is installed and on your PATH"

any help on how to fix this? I can't type anything w/o it continually popping up and stopping me.

Comment: Try typing python3 into terminal